# Can someone explain how LDRD arm instruction works?

Tags: assembly, arm, instructions

I just can't find any reasonable explanation about ldrd. What will end up in r2, what in r3? 
**ldrd   r2, r3, [r1]**

Comment: The _ARM Architecture Reference Manual_ (document DDI 0100E) explains this quite clearly.

Answer (score 12):

In simple terms, assuming the base address is correctly aligned, `ldrd r2, r3, [r1]` is equivalent to:

```
ldr r2, [r1]
ldr r3, [r1, #4]
```

There are various considerations around alignment and atomicity which depend on the exact architecture version and implementation details, but note that endianness is not one of them; the lower-addressed word always goes into the even-numbered register regardless.